# Sort out bad pictures of a dataset (k-means, clustering, sklearn)

Tags: python, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm testing some things in image retrival and i was thinking about how to sort out bad pictures of a dataset. For e.g there are only pictures  of houses and in between there is a  picture of people and some of cars. So at the end i want to get only the houses.
At the Moment my approach looks like:

- computing descriptors (Sift) of all pictures
- clustering all descriptors with k-means
- creating histograms of the pictures by computing the euclidean distance between the cluster centers and the descriptors of a picture
- clustering the histograms again.

at this moment i have got a first sort (which isn't really good). Now my Idea is to take all pictures which are clustered to a center with `len(center) > 1` and cluster them again and again. So the Result is that the pictures which are particular in a center will be sorted out. Maybe its enough to fit the result again to the same k-means without clustering again?!

the result isn't satisfying so maybe someone has got a good idea.

For Clustering etc. I'm using k-means of scikit learn.

Comment: Out of curiosity how many pictures do you have in your corpus, how many descriptors do you extract per pictures and how many centers to you compute for the clustering of the descriptors (the size of the visual word vocabulary)?

Comment: size of "dataset's" is variable between 100 - 1000. At the moment for the project up to 150 pictures, between 1000 and 4500 desc per picture => about 250 000 desc -> subsampling for k-means to 25 000. K is set to sqrt(n/2) where n = datapoints (first step) => K between 100 and 300) after that creating histograms and cluster histograms. The (second step) got about 6 to 10 Centers. I Will try your answer and post how it works...and I thinking about using "scipy.cluster.hierarchy" of scipy.

Comment: You probably need more data.

Answer (score 1):

K-means is not very robust to noise; and your "bad pictures" probably can be considered as such. Furthermore, k-means doesn't work too well for *sparse* data; as the means will not be sparse.

You may want to try other, more modern, clustering algorithms that can handle this situation much better.

Comment: do you think about UPGMC or WPGMC ?

Comment: These are hierarchical clustering variants, which is about as old as k-means. No, I was thinking about DBSCAN, OPTICS and such algorithms that are "just" 15 years old, not 50. And anything published this century, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the solution to your problem but here is a sanity check to perform prior to the final clustering, to check that the kind of features you extracted is suitable for your problem:

- extract the histogram features for all the pictures in your dataset
- compute the pairwise distances of all the pictures in your dataset using the histogram features (you can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distance`)

`np.argsort` the raveled distances matrix to find the indices of the 20 top closest pairs of distinct pictures according to your features (you have to filter out the zero-valued diagonal elements of the distance matrix) and do the same to extract the top 20 most farest pairs of pictures based on your histogram features.

Visualize (for instance with `plt.imshow`) the pictures of top closest pairs and check that they are all pairs that you would expect to be very similar.

Visualize the pictures of the top farest pairs and check that they are all very dissimilar.

If one of those 2 checks fails, then it means that histogram of bag of SIFT words is not suitable to your task. Maybe you need to extract other kinds of features (e.g. HoG features) or reorganized the way your extract the cluster of SIFT descriptors, maybe using a pyramidal pooling structure to extract info on the global layout of the pictures at various scales.

Comment: Well i have tried this and get results depending on k-means. Sometimes it fails and sometimes it is good...depending on random clusters. I get the descs from VLFeat so it will be just a little bit difficult to change something. I will try `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN`